# Unknown string format - parsing and converting python datetime string

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert the below to pandas datetime format using `dateutil.parser.parse` and `strftime`:

```
def getDateTimeFromISO8601String(s):
    d = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
    y = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I-%P')
    print(y)

s = '2018-10-13 01-am'
getDateTimeFromISO8601String(s)
```

But I'm getting the following error

> ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2018-10-13 01-am'

Comment: I think it's supposed to go the other way around - `dateutil.parser.parse('%Y-%m-%d %I-%P')` and `d.strftime(s)`

Comment: no, i tried it and it doesnt work.

Comment: i found the fix.     d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')